# Cannot connect to Google Hangouts account from Pidgin

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts, pidgin

I was able to use gMail (or Hangouts）account in Pidgin client a couple weeks ago. But lately, I got the "Not Authorized" message every time I tried to connect to my gMail account from Pidgin client.

Wondering if something has been changed, or connecting from Pidgin client to gMail (Hangouts) account is not supported anymore.

Here is the config in pidgin client:

```
In Basic tab:
    Protocol: XMPP
    Username: gmail account name (without @gmail.com)
    Domain: gmail.com
    Resource: Empty or gmail.com
    Password: password for password

In Advanced tab:
    Connection Security: tried all available options
    Connect port: 5222
    Connect server: talk.google.com
    File transfer proxies:
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here.  According to https://support.google.com/a/answer/49147 perhaps they simply shut down Google Talk already; Hangouts and Chat do not support XMPP.  You can try to use the native plugin https://bitbucket.org/EionRobb/purple-hangouts/wiki/Home